# Jupyter & Pandas - Change Tab Color when Dataframe is empty and only column headers?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Jupyter notebook that is running multiple dataframes to find data of issues. I am putting each of my dataframes on a separate tab of an excel sheet, so each sheet will either have data or just column headers.

What I am trying to figure out how to do is change the tab color to red when there is no data in the specific dataframe (when the tab only has the column headers).

I am using openpyxl to current open and save the sheets:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path, engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='TEST')
writer.save()
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try the the XlsxWriter.

from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

```
workbook = Workbook('worksheets.xlsx')

# Put together the worksheets.
WT1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
WT2 = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Now you can set the colors of the tabs
WT1.set_tab_color('blue')
WT2.set_tab_color('red')
```

Comment: I havnt used XlsxWriter because I am using dataframes with multiple tabs and dataframes, and I read that you cannot do that with XlsxWriter

Comment: It looks like you are already using the XlsxWriter from your example, and you can keep using it to just manipulate excel, and reserve pandas commands for other DF operations. See my second suggestion

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
# Check if DF only has headers and add code that you need to change color based on that condition

d = {'col1': [], 'col2': []}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

if len(df.index) == 0:
    WT2.set_tab_color('red')
```

Within the if statement, you should be able to use the XlsxWriter to just change color tabs.